# How to maximize downloading throughput by multi-threading

Tags: http, networking, optimization, download, web-crawler

I am using multi-threading to speed up the process of downloading a bunch of files from the Web.

How might I determine how many threads I should use to maximize or nearly maximize the total download throughput?

PS:

I am using my own laptop and the bandwidth is 1Mb.

The data I want is the webpage source code of *coursera.com*

Comment: Tell us more about the environment you're in.  Is this multi-threaded code running in a server room with high bandwidth?  On an arbitrary client machine?  And where is the data coming from, and what resources are available on the server side?

Answer (score 1):

There are much more factors than only number of threads if you want to speed up downloading files from network. Actually I don't believe that you will achieve this expect that there are some limitations you haven't described (like max bandwidth per connection on server side, you have multilink client and you can use different links do download different data, you want to download different parts from different servers, or similar).

In usual conditions having multiple threads to download something will slow the process. You will need to maintain couple of connections and somehow synchronise data (expect if you will download e.g. different files at the same time).

I would say that in "ordinary" conditions much bigger limitations are your bandwidth limit so using more threads will not make downloading faster. You will in this case share your whole bandwidth to many connections.